# dynamically create control using mvvm

Tags: c#, xaml, itemscontrol

I've been trying to create control dynamically and so far it is working. But my problem is the layout

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" >
                <ItemsControl IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ListControls}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="120*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="120*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label  Content="AN:" Margin="5,5,5,5" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
```

With the xaml above. this is the screenshot of the layout

[image]

and if i use a xaml like this

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
                <ItemsControl IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ListControls}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Label  Content="AN:" Margin="5,5,5,5" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox  Width="100" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
```

[image]

But my goal is i want the textbox to expand if the program is maximized.

How can i adjust the xaml code in order to expand the textbox? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly use `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` also remove `Width="100"`.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0"  Content="AN:" Margin="5,5,5,5" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Owww. the solution is really simple. Thank you so much. And its working